# Coudn't get textbox value

Tags: php

Here, I want to get value of textbox, but I coudn't.
Where am I wrong?
Is it must to use session if i want to get value of textbox?

```
<input type="submit" id="processorder" name="processorder" class="submit-green" value="Process Order"/>

    <?php
    foreach ($order_list as $row) 
    {
        ?>

         <td class="align-center"> 
         <input type="text" name="text[]" autocomplete="off" id="txtid_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" readonly value="<?php echo $text;?>">
        </td>
         </tr>
        <?php
        $i++;
        }
        ?>

    if(isset($_POST['processorder']))
    {
        $txtvalue = $_GET['text[]'];
        echo "helo".print_r($txtvalue);
    }
```

Comment: `$_GET['text[]']` to `$_GET['text']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is wrong,

```
$txtvalue = $_GET['text[]'];
```

it should be

```
$txtvalue = $_GET['text'];
                      ^ no [] here
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `$_GET['text[]']` to `$_GET['text']`

Answer (score 0):

The field would not be called `text[]` to PHP. It would just be called `text`, but would be an array instead of a string.

Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['processorder']))
{
    $arrayvalue = $_GET['text'];
    foreach($arrayvalue as $txtvalue){
        echo "helo" . $txtvalue . "<br>";
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your text input name is `text[]` with a bracket, it indicates that it is sending as an array, so to get the value you need

```
if (!empty($_POST["test"][0]) ) {
    $test_value = $_POST["test"][0];
}
```

I am using `0` here since your code only shows one input text, for the server-end will only receive one array value

Answer (score 0):

why you use array **name="text[]"** if you don't want to get multiple data using "text" than make it **name="text"**

```
<input type="text" name="text" autocomplete="off" id="txtid_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" readonly value="<?php echo $text;?>">
```

get value using

```
$_GET['text'] // get value
```

**or**

you want to multiple data using same name "Array"(mean using array)

```
<input type="text" name="text" autocomplete="off" id="txtid_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" readonly value="<?php echo $text;?>">
```

get value using

```
$_GET['text'][0] // 0 is a index value
```